# HTML/CSS components with Webpack (no framework)

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-component

How can I set up Webpack 4.5 to inject an html file, that has their own css file, into a main *index.html* without frameworks like Angular, React, etc. and without having a javaScript file for each html file I want to inject?

I've already created separate html files and inject them into *index.html*, but haven't figured out how to make those html templates have their own local-scoped css files.

Inside *home.html* I want to be able to use classes from *home.css*, like normal 

(i.e. not like `<div className={styles.foo}>`, which is the closest I've found)

#### home.html

```html
<div class=foo></div>
<div>
  <p class=bar></p>
</div>
```

#### home.css (local scope)

```css
.foo {background: red;}
.bar {background: green;}
```

and have it automatically locally-scoped so that in my *index.html* I can inject *home.html* without css conflicts and without having each .html file need it's own .js file.

#### index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="pages">
    <!-- inject page templates below -->
    <section id="home" class="page">${require("./pg-templates/home/home.html")}</section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### styles.css (global scope)

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.foo  /*this will be overridden by the .foo class in home.css*/
{
  background: yellow;
  color: purple;
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    port: 4200,
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html'}),
    new UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: /src/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs:[':data-src'],
            minimize: true,
            conservativeCollapse: false,
            interpolate: true
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Daniel I reworded the question to be more explicit

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can I know how you do (did) import your html files in a js?

Comment: @CristianTraìna to import html files into a js file I used `require('foo.html')`, but I have not imported a file directly into an html file which is what the question was about.

Comment: @slanden after all, I've posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355899/parse-an-html-template-as-you-require-it-in-javascript)